# Unexpected Tagnameexception occuring while selecting an option from dropdown box in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: xpath, drop-down-menu, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

The website which I am trying to automate is - http://www.lufthansa.com/online/portal/lh/ua/homepage
In the Search Flights form, there is a dropdown for selecting the number of passengers. I am handling it using the Select class. My code is as shown below -

```java
WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*@id='ns_7_CO19VHUC6N5PC0ACV6A7BG2I12_fmAdults']/tbody/tr/td[1]"));
Thread.sleep(3000L);
Select selectbox = new Select(dropdown);
Thread.sleep(3000L);
selectbox.selectByIndex(2);
```

I get the error as  -

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "td"**.

Now if I change my code as below it works absolutely fine.

```java
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*@id='ns_7_CO19VHUC6N5PC0ACV6A7BG2I12_fmAdults']/tbody/tr/td[1]")).click();
Thread.sleep(3000L);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='dijit_MenuItem_2_text']")).click();
```

I would like to handle this by using the fundamentals of Select, and not by the above mentioned method. Plese help. Let me know what am I missing here

Comment: It doesn't look like that site uses a `<select>` tag details here: https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html Try using a findby: https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html

Comment: So the second code snippet which I use is correct?

Comment: Correct. It finds that element by xpath. Perhaps try using a css selector instead and use findElements: https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/SearchContext.html#findElements%28org.openqa.selenium.By%29

Comment: yep, Select class expect the select element to work with, like "//select[id='bla']/option[2]", in case of this site it has table with role='listbox' containers as dropdowns instead of select elements

Comment: This is a dojo dropdown. Can anyone let me know on how to handle dojo dropdowns.

Comment: Can you elaborate what do you mean by "how to handle dojo dropdowns?". Do you mean how to select an option from the drop down? That you will have to do the way you've done above (2nd approach). Alternatively, After clicking on the drop down icon, you can capture all the option(td) elements. Then iterate over them to select the option you wanted. Let me know if u need any further help